# What is [Enum] from GetName()?

Tags: vb.net, types, enums

To get the name of an enum value, MSDN says to use:

```
[Enum].GetName(GetType(MyEnumTypeName), MyEnumValue)
'for e.g. if I have an enum for colours of the rainbow, then the following
[Enum].GetName(GetType(RainbowColours), 0)
'may return "Red"
```

Firstly, what is the `[Enum]` here? this is the first time I have come across square brackets used in this VB. Can I change this to:

```
[MyEnumTypeName].GetName(GetType(MyEnumTypeName), MyEnumValue)
```

Secondly, I have specified the underlying type of an enum to be `Byte` but VS will not allow me to directly specify this for the purposes of this statement

```
[Enum].GetName(Byte, MyEnumValue)
```

Can I use `GetName` in such a way that I don't also need to use `GetType`?

This combined would then maybe allow me to use:

```
[MyEnumTypeName].GetName(MyEnumType, MyEnumValue)
```

Comment: just found that square brackets allow keywords to be used as types

Comment: The [] syntax delimits the use of a keyword as a type.

Comment: So I could use `[MyEnumTypeName].GetType(GetType(MyEnumTypeName), MyEnumValue)`?

Comment: Or even `[MyenumtypeName].GetName([MyEnumTypeName], MyEnumValue)`

Comment: Well Vs allows my first comment but not my second. Im not quite understanding the difference between a type and a Type it seems...? So whats the difference between `Byte` or `MyEnumType` and the `Type` specified as the parameter for GetType(enumType As type, value As Object)?

Comment: The square brackets are only needed around keywords, so you don't need them around your own class names.  [`GetName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a shared method on the `Enum` class, but since `Enum` is also a VB.NET keyword, it needs to be escaped with the square brackets.  Why do you want to avoid using `GetType`?

Comment: @Mark, Thanks. Because I already know the type so why should I ask the program to go do more work than it needs to? In fact it's already specified if I write `MyEnumType.GetName()` why should the method have to have it specified twice, once specifically and once dynamically (in the first parameter) for it?

Comment: Browsing MSDN it seems my understanding of types is broken at the point where a type _object_ (an object that represents a type such as a Byte) differs from an _actual_ type (e.g. a Byte). VB is exhausting in its duplication :(

Comment: An instance of [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), as returned by the [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx) operator provides access to the metadata for the type, while the type name is just... a name, I suppose.  C# would be the same - except using [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx), so it's not a VB.NET thing.

Comment: @Mark Thanks again, thats a helpful explanation. Im used to C where a type is unequivocally a type is unequivocally a type. But then C doesn't have reflection :)

Comment: Why you not using `MyEnumValue.ToString("G")` for getting name of then `Enum` value

Comment: @Fabio, Good idea and simpler. But not exactly the same, if the value is not part of the enumeration it gives the string of the numeric value, whereas the `GetName()` method would return `Nothing` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, square brackets around a variable name just allow you to use a keyword for that object's variable name. They aren't needed in your case. So, continuing on...

The docs for the Enum.GetName method:
[Enum.GetName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Public Shared Function GetName ( _
    enumType As Type, _
        value As Object _
) As String
```

You can't simply do:

```
MyEnumTypeName.GetName(MyEnumType, MyEnumValue)
```

Without declaring a variable of type `Type` named `MyEnumType`. You need an object of type `Type` to fill in for the first parameter. If you were to pass the name of your Enum, it doesn't accomplish the same thing. You could, however, do the following:

```
Dim MyEnumType As Type = GetType(MyEnumTypeName)
MyEnumTypeName.GetName(MyEnumType, MyEnumValue)
```

If you were to declare `MyEnumType` as a class level variable so that you only need to set it once, then that would at least solve the issue you ask about in the comments above to stop the program from doing "more work than it needs to".

Comment: An object of type `Type` is the bit I was stuck on, I had though type and `Type` were one and the same. Ta!